# Using Web Workers to run AngularJS functions like $interval?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-worker

So I recently decided to make an idle game from AngularJS, but after a few days of coding it I realized a problem.

The $interval function slows down a **huge** amount when not actively looking at the screen.

Searching on Google and stackoverflow took me to web workers, and one post actually had me figure out how to make a factory of a web worker to implement into my controller, but I was never able to figure out how to make them run functions (or if this is even possible).

```js
myApp.factory("interval", ['$q',
  function($q) {
    var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([
      'function addInterval() {' +
      'i = "add()";' +
      'postMessage(i);' +
      'setTimeout("addInterval()", 10);' +
      '}' +
      'addInterval();' +
      'function saveInterval() {' +
      'x = "save()";' +
      'postMessage(x);' +
      'setTimeout("saveInterval()", 30000);' +
      '}' +
      'saveInterval();'
    ], {
      type: 'application/javascript'
    }));

    var worker = new Worker(blobURL);
    var defer = $q.defer();

    worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
      defer.resolve(e.data);
    }, false);

    return {
      doWork: function(myData) {
        defer = $q.defer();
        worker.postMessage(myData); // Send data to our worker. 
        return defer.promise;
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

I practically want to know if it's possible to have the web workers run my save() and interval() functions that are in the controller. I tried to console.log(defer.resolve(e.data)), but it returned undefined.
...and I literally have no clue what the deferring/resolving/promising even does.

Thanks!

Comment: Unlikely without some extreme hacking - web workers don't have access to your main thread beyond simple value passing through `postMessage`.  You could trigger these functions to be run from the web worker, but not actually run it themselves.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: It's probably best I just change the time on the interval functions to running every second instead of 10 ms. Though, if there's a way to use the web workers to make it seem like the page is still active so that the intervals don't die without actually doing anything...that would work. Thanks Scott!

Answer (score 0):

So after Scott corrected me about how web workers function I decided to set the interval from 10ms to 1000ms...and was defeated...

...but then I got the great idea of "How about instead of making it one fixed rate, I'll cancel the interval upon page/tab blur (not focussed) and change the intervals + divisions accordingly!". This is what I came up with that solved my problems and made the game continue to run - even when not viewing it.

```
$scope.division = 100;
var x = $interval(add, 10);
angular.element($window).bind('focus', function() {
  $scope.division = 100;
  $interval.cancel(x);
  x = $interval(add, 10);
}).bind('blur', function() {
  $scope.division = 1;
  $interval.cancel(x);
  x = $interval(add, 1000);
});
```